# Cannot push to Heroku using Git no matter what I do

Tags: python, git, heroku

Edit: I'm an idiot. I needed to use `cd` to actually tell Git to go to the repository. I found the solution.

I have been running around in circles trying to figure this out. I created a Discord bot and I'm trying to use Git and Heroku to host it. I've successfully gotten to the step that enables me to actually push it, but then it gives me an error.

First, my method of approach.

`git add .` wasn't working for me. So I specified a file directory that goes to my bot. If I *do* put `git add .` in Git Bash, I get this error message:

```
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/ElevatedDiagnostics/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/History/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Low/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temp/iu-14D2N.tmp/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temp/WinSAT/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Pictures/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .bash_history.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .lesshst.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in AppData/Local/AVG/Antivirus/datascan.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: open("AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file 'AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx'
fatal: adding files failed
```

I have tried running it as an administrator. The following message appears:

```
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/Application Data/': Function not implemented
```

It just. . . Freezes and it cannot do anything. I need to go into it's files and manually remove a file that caused it to break.

Anyways, `git add .` was not an answer. So, like I said, I specified the directory. It accepted it and then I did the following command: `git commit -am "test"`. . . *and it worked.*
Now, the issue is the following error message when I run `git push heroku master`:

```
Enumerating objects: 65, done.
Counting objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (46/46), done.
Writing objects: 100% (65/65), 2.84 MiB | 1.02 MiB/s, done.
Total 65 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: bf75a0363f71778460026f132e502c0b02c5b388
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version bf75a0363f71778460026f132e502c0b02c5b388
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to discord-mod5.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/discord-mod5.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/discord-mod5.git'
```

(I have attempted to commit multiple times in ignorace, hence the "Warning: triggered twice" portion. Same thing still happens when I make a new commit).

Right there is where I hit a road block. Nothing was working. I deleted and re-installed Git Bash. Nothing. Ran as an administrator. Nothing. Changed buildpacks and added/removed them. Nothing. Changed `requirements.txt`, `Procfile`, and `runtime.txt` file contents. Nothing. renamed `requirements.txt` to `requirement.txt`. Nothing. Initialized in the root using `git init` and I even specified multiple directories leading up to the bot. Nothing worked.

I am back to the start. What am I doing wrong, what is happening, and what is the solution?

Contents that I'm trying to push (in this order):

- .git(from when I initialized)
- main.py
- prefixes.json
- Procifle
- requirements.txt
- runtime.txt

Comment: A whole bunch of those directories have no business being part of your repository. Where does your project live on your local filesystem?

Comment: "I have tried running it as an administrator"—please _don't_ do this. Running with elevated privileges should only be done when you fully understand why they are needed, and only _if_ they are needed. Blindly running things as Administrator when they don't work as a regular user is a great way to break your system.

Comment: "Anyways, `git add .` was not an answer. So, like I said, I specified the directory."—where are you when you are trying to run `git add .`? And what, exactly, do you mean by "I specified the directory"?

Comment: "I deleted and re-installed Git Bash. Nothing. Ran as an administrator. Nothing. Changed buildpacks and added/removed them. Nothing. Changed `requirements.txt`, `Procfile`, and `runtime.txt` file contents. Nothing. renamed `requirements.txt` to `requirement.txt`. Nothing. Initialized in the root using `git init` and I even specified multiple directories leading up to the bot. Nothing worked."—please stop guessing. Nothing suggests any problem with your `Procfile`, buildpacks, or `runtime.txt`, and your requirements file should be called `requirements.txt`. Re-initializing your repo won't help.

Comment: I ran it as an administrator to attempt to resolve the permission denied errors, and the others were out of desperation. When I did `git add` I put the path to my bot after the command.

Comment: But why are you getting permission denied errors? And why are all those directories showing up? Should they be in your repository? Absolutely not. So the solution isn't to cram them in using an Administrator hammer, it's to figure out why Git is trying to include them and then change what you're doing so they _aren't_ included.

Comment: _Again_, where are you when you run `git add .`? And what do you mean by "I specified the directory"? Normally you'd be _in_ the project directory when you `git add`.

Comment: I ran `git add .` after running `git init`. I did `git add C:/Users/username/To/Project`. I see now that I didn't specify the repository by doing `cd C:/Users/username/To/Project` *then* `git init` and so it was throwing an error.

Comment: Yes, `git init` will create a repository wherever you happen to be. If your repository contains a bunch of things it shouldn't, all kinds of bad things can happen: (a) you may commit sensitive private documents, (b) your repository size will be huge, (c) you'll be pushing the wrong thing to Heroku, etc. I strongly suggest you learn the basics of Git before going much farther. You should know where your repository is, what it contains, how to see those things, how to look at your history, etc. There are lots of tools to help you commit the right things; `git add .` is rarely on that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your home directory is set up as a Git repository and you're trying to add everything there to your project.  Windows is very strict about what programs it allows access to certain directories, like Documents, and as a result, your attempt to add everything to the repository with `git add .` was unsuccessful.

First, in Git Bash, type `cd` to go to your home directory.  Then, run `mv .git .git.bak`.  That will make your home directory no longer a Git repository, but it will preserve the directory in case you had anything important in there.

Then, go into your project directory with `cd`.  This should definitely be a directory *other* than your home directory.  We'll pretend it's called `discord-mod5`.  Run `git init` to initialize the repository, and then run `git add .` and then commit.

Comment: It still gave me a bunch of errors. I'm new to a lot of this, sorry. It giving me a "Permission Denied" error, followed by a lot of directories similar to my first attempt at `git add .`